# splitting strings using regex in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I have the following a really long list of strings that look like the following that I want to split it into several pieces.

```
strings<-c("https://www.website.com/stats/stat.227.y2020.eon.t879.html",
"https://www.website.com/stats/stat.229.y2019.eoff.t476.html")
```

and the desired output is as below:

```
links                                     Year    Seas     Tour 
https://www.website.com/stats/stat.227.   y2020    eon     t879
https://www.website.com/stats/stat.229.   y2019   eoff     t476
```

How can I achieve this using regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str_match` :

```
stringr::str_match(strings, '.*\\.(y\\d+)\\.(\\w+)\\.(t\\d+)')
```

---

You can use the same regex in `tidyr::extract` if you put `strings` in a dataframe.

```
tidyr::extract(data.frame(strings), strings, c("Year","Seas", "Tour"), 
              '\\.(y\\d+)\\.(\\w+)\\.(t\\d+)', remove = FALSE)

#                                                      strings  Year Seas Tour
#1  https://www.pgatour.com/stats/stat.227.y2020.eon.t879.html y2020  eon t879
#2 https://www.pgatour.com/stats/stat.229.y2019.eoff.t476.html y2019 eoff t476
```

Here, we capture data in 3 parts (capture groups)

1st part - `'y'` followed by a number

2nd part - next word following part 1

3rd part `'t'` followed by a number.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *{unglue}* :

```r
library(unglue)
unglue::unglue_data(
  strings, "{links}.{Year=[^.]+}.{Seas=[^.]+}.{Tour=[^.]+}.html")
#>                                    links  Year Seas Tour
#> 1 https://www.website.com/stats/stat.227 y2020  eon t879
#> 2 https://www.website.com/stats/stat.229 y2019 eoff t476
```

here `"[^.]+"` means "one or more non dot characters", which is what we want for Year, Seas, and Tour.